# Line disappears when column legend is used (Stacked column line report)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have report where I wanna show 11 Bins where allegations are counted to the different bins. As well I wanna show a limit line.
Like here:
[image]

But when I show how often an allegation is in a bin (using column legend) then my limit line is only shown when there are allegations in a bin.
Like here:
[image]

I have no idea how I can show the whole limit line from bin 1 - 11.
Maybe there is another to show such limit line.

Btw. How can I define that each bin is numbered on x-axis?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can see the forest for the trees.
After I switched from clustered columns/lines to clustered columns everything went as desired.